# How to Use .jks file in node js to submit request on https endpoint

Tags: java, node.js, ssl, https, jks

I am looking to use .jks file node js code in similar fashion we do in java keystore. I found solution where people used jks to create .pem file then use them in code but. But we can not create pem file from jks as it contains multiple certificates so need to use it similar to java.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with jks-js npm module for converting the JKS to PEM, to make http service calls from the NodeJS modules.

```
const keystore = jks.toPem(
fs.readFileSync('keystore.jks'),
'password'
);
```